# can chrome.runtime.sendMessage be caught by the website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and I wonder if I use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in my extension on some websites, can website owner catch me and get what I am sending to or from other browser tabs? Some people argues that there is a way, but nobody can prove or show the example of this. Since the communication between tabs are made internally how website owner can catch and trace this behaviour?

Comment: Possible only if this is an [`externally_connectable` sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) inside a MAIN world script. The default content script is in the ISOLATED world, which cannot be seen by the page, unless it finds a way to hack the browser via a side channel attack like Spectre.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so it is less likely that the big companies like betting websites would do that "hacking" for getting sendMessage activity.